# git include changes from previous commits

Tags: git

I have a master branch. On some `t` day I merged new files to the master, but realised that these files caused some bugs. I created a new branch (from master), in this branch, I deleted all the changes of the previous commit and committed it to master. Things go as usual, and there has been few more unrelated commits to master. Today, I realised that the issue was not caused by all the files, but only a small bug fix. So, I am trying to bring back all those files (along with bugfix), but unable to do so. I was thinking if I create a new branch from the point when I committed those files originally, I would get back the files, but it just shows up as a blank branch (no changes) when I try to merge to master?

I am sorry, I am not that familiar with git here. My most of the use has been limited to just `git pull` and `git push`. Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You could simply revert the commit which removed the files: `git revert commit-that-deleted-the-files`.

Comment: That's not gonna fly. The commits have been _merged_ so git won't consider them to be merged into the branch again. I have already answered this same thing multiple times (and how to go around it)... let me see if I can find one of those posts so that I can mark this is a duplicate.

Comment: WTH.... won't waste more time hunting this down. Let me write the answer and keep this as a favorite, given that it comes up every once in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... suppose you have this:

```
* GGG Last commit in main branch (main)
* FFF Merging feature1 in main branch
|\
* | EEE Third commit in main branch
| * DDD another commit in a feature branch (feature1)
| * CCC Some commit in a feature branch
|/
* BBB second commit
* AAA first commit
```

So, what you can do is, first:

```
git checkout -b blah $( git merge-base FFF^ FFF^2 ) # go back to the commit where the 2 branches diverged
```

With that, you get:

```
* GGG Last commit in main branch (main)
* FFF Merging feature1 in main branch
|\
* | EEE Third commit in main branch
| * DDD another commit in a feature branch (feature1)
| * CCC Some commit in a feature branch
|/
* BBB second commit (HEAD -> blah)
* AAA first commit
```

Now, let's cherry-pick the original commits of `feature1`:

```
git cherry-pick HEAD..feature1
```

Now, you have this (not ordered chronologically, anyway):

```
* GGG Last commit in main branch (main)
* FFF Merging feature1 in main branch
|\
* | EEE Third commit in main branch
| * DDD another commit in feature branch (feature1)
| * CCC Some commit in feature branch
|/
|
| * DDD' another commit in a feature branch (HEAD -> blah)
| * CCC' Some commit in a feature branch
|/
* BBB second commit (HEAD -> main)
* AAA first commit
```

And to git, `blah` has *not* been merged into `main` even though it is equivalent to `feature1`. If you merge `blah`, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

## Follow These Steps to Retrieve Your Missing Files

We are going to go back to the previous commit, so if you have any uncommitted changes at the moment, please either *commit* them or (if you're not ready to commit) *stash* them. I explain stashing below.

### If You're Stashing Them

Run `git add -A` to stage any current changes in the working directory, so if you added new files, they are saved before you stash. Then, run `git stash`.

### After You've Either Committed or Stashed

- Run `git log --oneline --all --graph --reflog`. This will show you a full view of your blobs, branches, and history.

  - Use the arrow keys to navigate, if needed. Press the **q** key to exit this view.
- Locate the blob that has `HEAD` next to it. This is your current position. There should be  7-character code before it. This is the ID of your blob. Note this. Make sure you use your actual blob ID and not the one in the example picture that I am showing you (do not use "1A2B123")
  [image: Example of where this blob ID is located (in this case 1A2B123)]
- Locate the blob that has the version of the files that you need. Note this blob ID as well.
- Use `git reset --hard <blobId>` to go back to the version with the files.
- Copy the files to wherever you want, such as your Desktop.
- Use `git reset --hard <blobId>` to go back to your most recent version.
- If you stashed earlier, then run `git stash pop` to retrieve those uncommitted changes from before.

You can now copy your files back into your project and commit them/push them if you want.